Keras: извлечение связанных словосочетаний
Какую архитектуру выбрать для решения подобной задачи?
Нужно, чтобы модель, получая на вход предложение:
"Кандидоз полости рта – микотическая инфекция полости рта, вызванная условно-патогенными дрожжеподобными грибами Candida albicans."
на выходе разбивала исходное предложение на логические связи:
"Кандидоз полости рта – микотическая инфекция"
"Кандидоз полости рта – полость рта"
"Кандидоз полости рта – Candida albicans"
"Candida albicans – условно-патогенный"
"Candida albicans – дрожжеподобный гриб"
Морфологический анализатор для нормализации слов и определения грамматических форм я сделал. Немного изучил информацию, нашел, что такая задача чем-то похожа на POS-tagging, но не могу понять как "объяснить" модели, что нужно найти последовательно в цикле связи каждого слова предложения.
